# Remove duplicate array key

Tags: php

Array structure

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 15710
    "sale_id" => 6699
    "item_id" => 300
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => 15711
    "sale_id" => 6699
    "item_id" => 300
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to remove the second array if there have same `item_id`. Therefore, i referred to the `array_unique` but it seems does not work.

Code

```
$test = array_unique($model->items->toArray(), SORT_REGULAR);
Debugbar::addMessage($test,'test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your array is sorted by `id` and  in case of duplicate you want to preserve the item with the smallest `id`:

```
$newArr = [];

foreach(array_reverse($arr) as $v) {
    $newArr[$v['item_id']] = $v;
}

$newArr = array_values($newArr);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/9F0j9)

Answer (score 1):

Well, array_unique won't go deep as you wish. 
You may achieve that by using the following code:

```
$uniqueItems = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item){
    if(!key_exists($item['item_id'], $carry)){
        $carry[$item['item_id']] = $item;
    }

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

If you want to have an indexed array again you may use:

```
$indexedArray = array_values($uniqueItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

An old snippet from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#116302) site that should help you in this case,

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/v5k1j